# Classic asp - response.redirect in a sub - error handling

Tags: asp-classic, error-handling

I wish to do the following ... Provide a page a developer can redirect to provided an error occurs ... like a vb error connection couldn't open or object couldn't be found ... or a database error is raised ... but since I moved the redirect into a sub the page doesn't actually redirect ... Is it possible that I simply can't redirect from a sub? Seems weird.

Run a stored procedure that raises an error

```
Dim cmd
Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmd.ActiveConnection = con
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.CommandText = "spReturnDBException"
cmd.Execute
```

Call a handle errors function that sets up some session parms and redirects if neccessary

```
HandleErrors con _
            , Request.ServerVariables("PATH_INFO") _
            , "An error occurred while trying to save sessions." _
            , "Actual Error: " + Err.Description + " EmpNo: " + Session("EmpNo") _
            + ".  QueryString: " + Request.Querystring _
            , 0
```

This would be the sub called.

```
sub HandleErrors( connection, WebPagePath, GenericErrorMessage, DebugInfo, Severity)


//Check for vb errors
if Err.Number <> 0 Then

    Session("WebPagePath") = WebPagePath 
    Session("SafeErrorMessage") = GenericErrorMessage 'Session("SafeErrorMessage") + "A connection was dropped while trying to complete sessions."
    Session("DebugInfo") = DebugInfo ' Err.Description
    Session("LineNo") = Err.Line 
    Session("StackTrace") = "" 
    Session("Severity") = Severity 

    response.redirect("Error.asp")  

    //error occurs
elseif connection.Errors.count <> 0 then 

    response.write("a database error occurred.")
    // Store safe error message / # in session
    Session("WebPagePath") = WebPagePath 
    Session("SafeErrorMessage") = GenericErrorMessage 'Session("SafeErrorMessage") + "An error has occurred while trying to save sessions."
    Session("DebugInfo") = DebugInfo '"Some extra added debug info from the webpage"
    Session("LineNo") = 0 
    Session("StackTrace") = ""
    Session("Severity") = Severity

    Dim objError
    for each objError in connection.Errors

        // Store safe error number in session
        Session("SafeErrorNumbers") = Session("SafeErrorNumbers") + objError.Description
        if connection.Errors.Count > 1 then
            Session("SafeErrorNumbers") = Session("SafeErrorNumbers") + "|"
        end if 

    next 

    response.Redirect("Error.asp")  
end if

Err.Clear

end sub
```

Comment: @Robert If i turn off "On error resume next" I am getting the error that is raised in the procedure ... which is what I expect. If I set "On error resume next" then the redirect just doesn't occur and i end up sitting on my original page and nothing happens.

Comment: can you change to a function and return the redirect page to the calling page and have that page do the `response.redirect()`

Comment: do you mean something like response.redirect handleErrors  and then have handleErrors return the page to be redirected to? What happens if there is no error? Will response.redirect simply not do anything if I return an empty string?

Comment: Reponse.Redirect will work no matter where you place it in code.  The problem will be that for some reason that line of code is not being reached.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones I've confirmed by using response.write that piece of code is being executed. Or rather if I am specific I've confirmed that if block does get executed.

Comment: does turning on "On error resume next" get you into the handleError sub routine? can you response.write() something before the if statement.

Comment: So the problem was that the on error resume next was hiding a problem in the handle errors sub / function. For some reason the Err.Line was/is invalid and although it was making it into sub / function and the if statement as it went through the if statement it hit that line of code and quit executing. @AnthonyWJones was correct the redirect does work from inside a sub or function. Does anyone know why Err.Line doesn't work? Is it even a valid line of code. I got it from somewhere on Stack ... I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display the Error line number:

```
set objError = Server.GetLastError()
strErrorLine =  objError.Line
```

Here are a couple threads on using Err.line:

http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/asp/threads/11615

http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?279612-ASP-Error-Handling.-Err.Line-weird-behavior

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain why you are getting the results you are.  I can tell you that if your code reachs a line that contains `Response.Redirect` that redirect will happen regardless of whether its a in a Sub procdure or not.

I would make this suggestion.  Stop using using `On Error Resume Next`. It is very painful way to deal with exceptions.

Instead change `HandleErrors` into `GenerateConnectionError`.  Its job would be to compose error source and description strings and deliberately call `Err.Raise` with a user define error number (I tend to use 1001).

Now your `Error.asp` should be installed in the root of your application as the handler for the 500.100 http status code.  When a script error occurs IIS will look to the current error pages collection for the location to determine what to do.  You will have set this to execute a URL and specified your `Error.asp` as the URL.

When Error.asp is executed it will find details about the page being requested from `QueryString`.  Here you can also use `Server.GetLastError` to get an [`ASPError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524942%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) object from which you can get other details about the error.

Using this approach will detail with any script error without requiring the developer to remember to pepper their code with `HandleError` code.  The developer need on remember to call `GenerateConnectionError` when performing code that is using an ADODB.Connection and even then you could probably abstract that inside an .asp include file.

Comment: Anthony you were correct as I indicated in the comments above ... the resume next was hiding the fact that Err.Line is not supported in asp. So at the moment I've lost the line number functionality but everything else works as it's supposed to ... a call to Handle errors now redirects if an error is raised or does not if it's not necessary. So all we have to do to add error handling is set on error resume next and then call handlErrors where we expect a possible error. Thanks very much for your help ... your insistance that I was wrong was what helped me find the problem.

Comment: @Kevin:  I'm glad you've got a solution. I do hope you are only using On Error Resume Next in small functions and aren't setting it globally.  A global On Error Resume Next is a debugging nightmare and where attempts are made to handle errors via Err.Number just clutters up the code (which generally leads to more bugs).  You perhaps may not be happy to hear that and it may be too ingrained in your app to do anything about but its best you know than not.